# which performance are better? ngx-translate Directive or Pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, multilingual, angular-pipe, ngx-translate

I'm using [ngx-translate 11.x](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) with angular 7 in a huge project.

When use `pipe` transform show first empty string And when use `directive`, show first path to translate string.

*Directive way*: `<span [translate]="HELLO'"></span>`

*Pipe way*: `<span >{{'HELLO'| translate}}</span>`

**Now, Which performance are better?**

Comment: Well if you're looking for performance, the built-in i18n tool is the best one, since you compile every project into a different language. Otherwise, I would say the pipe, because directives are heavier since they manipulate the HTML while the pipe only transforms the data that is provided to them, but I'm not sure.

Comment: AFAIK the `translate` pipe implementation is impure so there might be some performance hits (multiple instances for each component, pipe called on each change detection cycle, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There is the official [i18n module](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) for performances.
Also with *ngx-translate* you can write something like this: `<span [innerHtml]="'HELLO'" translate></span>`